# A problem with cosine function

Tags: complex-analysis, number-theory

I try to understand something from number theory and the author gave this as an excersise: Prove that $z\longmapsto 2\sqrt{p}\cos z$ is a bijection of a set $\Theta_{p}=\left[i\log\sqrt{p},0\right]\cup\left[0,\pi\right]\cup\left[\pi,\pi+i\log\sqrt{p}\right]$ onto $\left[-\left(p+1\right),p+1\right]$. Here $p>2$ is a prime number. I proved that the picture lies in $\left[-\left(p+1\right),p+1\right]$, but injection and sirjection I can't prove. Help.